# Why non-root python installation can work across the whole cluster?

Tags: python, root, cluster, datascience-anaconda

I recently installed anaconda (which includes a python3) locally in my account folder on a cluster with a dozen of nodes (each node with several cores). I use it to install some package P that is used in certain python programs.
--- In short, I probably can say I just non-root installed a python locally.

I originally presumed that I can python3 run the program with P only on the node where I installed them, which is presumably the portal node of the cluster. However, I notice that I can actually even submit jobs of such programs running on any nodes on the cluster. I also made sure that I indeed use the newly installed python3.x from anaconda, not the python2.x already there long before.
This happens on two different clusters (one with PBS job system, the other with LSF Lava).

So why is this possible?

Comment: why not? Assuming your home directory is visible identically on each node of the cluster, all nodes see exactly the same files, similarly to what they would see if you'd installed it on each node individually. Of course any system libraries it depends on need to be present on all nodes, but nodes like that are probably identical in that, too. All the installer needs to do is to _not_ have arbitrary dependencies on the hostname or other such identifiers.

Comment: @ilkkachu I don't understand the difference between my locally installed python and package P and 'any system libraries it depends on need to be present on all nodes'.